# accessing https://myIP gives unsecure connection, how to redirect to secured domain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL-certificate for my domain which works well.

However, if I go to https://111.111.111.111 (not the real IP), I get a message: *Unsecure connection, certificate not trusted*. Of course this is perfectly correct, because I don't have a certificate for the IP, which I will not get either (Lets Encrypt doesn't do that).

I've been puzzling with the Apache2 config files and the .htaccess file to redirect any request to https://111.111.111.111 towards my real domain https://www.example.com.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works well if I try to connect to **http**://111.111.111.111, but *not* when I connect to **https**://111.111.111.111

My initial thought was to add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https$ [NC]
```

above

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
```

But that doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: The problem is: when you try to connect to `https://yourip` then your browser tries to establish a secure connection (key exchange and such). It is not possible to forward someone without connecting first. Imagine if someone could do a man in the middle attack against a https website and silently redirect you, very unsafe.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this is not fixable without getting a certificate on the IP address itself?

Comment: Yes. And in times of ubiquitous https, nobody really expects to access web servers through IP addresses anyway. That's what SNI is for: A single IP address can host any number of servers (different host names). Also: This question is not programming related (see [help/on-topic]) but rather a setup-related question, thus not a good fit for stackoverflow

Comment: It is an error thrown by https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/ when checking the website. But It seems to be a rather unfixable error for most people then. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If your site's `<VirtualHost>` is accepting requests to this IP address then the user would be redirected after they have clicked through the browser warning and accepted the "unsecure certificate". Needless to say, this is not a recommended course of action for the user to take. Alternatively, ensure that [direct requests to the server's IP address do not resolve to your website to begin with](https://serverfault.com/a/914657/49157) - This needs to be done at the server level by creating a default vHost container to catch these requests.

Answer (score 1):

On your **ssl conf** do the following:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<your ip>'">
    Redirect permanent / https://yourdomain.com/
</If>
```

In your example this is:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '111.111.111.111'">
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</If>
```

**Redirect** is under

```
modules/mod_alias.so
```

so to enable the module for your server, go on your **mods-enabled** direcotry and do the following, if the symlink is missing

```
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/alias.conf alias.conf
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/alias.load alias.load
```